# Ampersand (&) not working in SAS data step

Tags: sas

I wrote a SAS code for my data to contain space between the first name and last name. So in order to do so I used '&' operator in the input statement. But its not working. Here is the code below

```
data SpacedInput;
input ID Name & $30. Score;
Cards;
101 Base Sas 34
102 Cisco Telephone 45
103 Xonxiangnam Samnuelnarayan 32
;
run;
```

The output table contains the data in the following format:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` causes the input pointer to seek two consecutive spaces before it starts reading in the next variable in your input statement. If you add some extra spaces to your datalines, it should work as you're expecting:

```
data SpacedInput;
input ID Name & $30. Score;
Cards;
101 Base Sas  34
102 Cisco Telephone  45
103 Xonxiangnam Samnuelnarayan  32
;
run;
```